# Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^m$, $B \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and $f:A \to B$ be a diffeomorphism. Then $m = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

In proving the dimension of a manifold is well-defined, I have come across this lemma. Could you check if my proof is fine or if it contains subtle logical mistakes?

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R^m$, $B \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and $f:A \to B$ be a diffeomorphism. Then $m = n$.

**Proof:** Let $f^{-1}$ be the two-sided inverse of $f$. Then $f^{-1}:B \to A$ is also a diffeomorphism. Fix $a \in A$ and let $b := f(a) \in B$. Then $\mathrm d f (a) \in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^m, \mathbb R^n)$, i.e., $\mathrm d f (a)$ is a continuous linear map from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^n$. Similarly, $\mathrm d f^{-1} (b)$ is a continuous linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$.

Clearly, $g:=f \circ f^{-1}$ is the identity map from $B$ to $B$. Hence $\mathrm d g (b)$ is the identity map on $\mathbb R^n$. On the other hand, $\mathrm d g (b) = \mathrm d f (f^{-1}(b)) \circ \mathrm d f^{-1} (b) =  \mathrm d f (a) \circ \mathrm d f^{-1} (b)$ by chain rule. This means $\mathrm d f (a)$ is the left inverse of $\mathrm d f^{-1} (b)$.

A similar argument with $g:=f^{-1} \circ f$ implies $\mathrm d f (a)$ is the right inverse of $\mathrm d f^{-1} (b)$. Hence $\mathrm d f (a)$ is the two-sided inverse of $\mathrm d f^{-1} (b)$. It follows that $\mathrm d f (a)$ is bijective and thus $\mathrm d f (a)$ is an isomorphism. It follows that $m=n$.

**Update:**  I was sloppy. I should have restricted that $A,B$ are open. IMHO,  we can extend the definition of differentiability to arbitrary set like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871600/definition-of-differentiability-on-closed-sets), but diffeomorphism makes sense only for open domain.

Comment: Looks good $\space$

Comment: Wait, does this mean $A=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y,z)\mid x^2+y^2=1,z=0\}$ are not diffeomorphic?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was sloppy. I should have restricted that $A,B$ are open. IMHO,  we can extend the definition of differentiability to arbitrary set like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3871600/definition-of-differentiability-on-closed-sets), but diffeomorphism makes sense only for open domain. Please correct If I'm wrong :)

Comment: If you should have written something else, don’t argue here, edit your question. @Akira

Comment: Don’t correct your question at the end, make it non-sloppy. Just put the condition in the Lemma.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't understand your suggestion. It would be clearer and less disturbing for later people if I make update rather than change the original content.

Comment: As edited, it requires a person to read all the way through your question to understand the proof part of your post. Just make your question clear. You don’t need to add “update” to the end so that people who read it know the history.